# Process 3 MB of data in IBM

Tags: ibm-q-experience

How can I process a 3 MB csv file in IBMQ?

The memory shows 433 MB. Is this the maximum file size that I can upload and process in IBMQ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please add more details? What kind of data (e.g. inital states of qubits)?

Comment: The data is raw csv file I downloaded from UCI. Preprocessed it for missing values and wants to upload it to IBM X so that I can run codes.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that. I have uploaded file around 11 MB before and it works fine.

Comment: What memory are you referring to? If you are talking about the Memory on the top of the notebook then that is the memory that is being allocated to you for your work.

Comment: Thanks to all. Instead of uploading csv data to IBMQ I changed to backend pointing to a quantum computer of suitable qubits. I did every processing in my local system.